# e <= 3v - 6 for planar graph question: why does every face (of a planar graph) have to have at least three sides?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs, eulerian-path

Can't we make a face with just two edges(sides) and two vertices? We just connect those two vertices twice each with different edges and we can make a face between the two edges with only two vertices and edges like the image.
[image]

Comment: (i) The inequality $e\leq 3v-6$ holds only for connected simple planar graphs with at least 3 vertices.   Your graph is not simple, and has only 2 vertices.

Comment: (ii) It is not true that every face in a planar graph must have at least three sides. The planar graph with 1 vertex, 0 edges and 1 face clearly has one face with 0 sides.

Comment: (iii) In a connected, simple planar graph with at least 3 vertices, each face has at least 3 sides. And if there are at least 3 vertices, then the "smallest" possible face that can be formed is a triangle.

Comment: The essential part of Randy Marsh's comments is: the theorem is about simple graphs.  (It is easy to see that non-simple planar graphs on $n$ vertices can have arbitrarily many edges: you can always add as many parallel edges to a single edge as you like, just as in your picture.)